# How to convert unicodes in json string to normal (plain)strings in python

Tags: python, json, unicode

Example :

```
s = "[{"course_id": u"1", "course_name": u"Angular", "course_img":       "sas"},
      {"course_id": u"2", "course_name": u"SMAI", "course_img": "ASD"}, 
     ]"
```

I need to convert this to normal json string.How to achieve this?

Comment: This isn't even valid Python syntax. Is that really a string? Why don't you post your actual code?

Answer (score 1):

If you had normal python list like this

```
s = [{"course_id": u"1", "course_name": u"Angular", "course_img": "sas"},
  {"course_id": u"2", "course_name": u"SMAI", "course_img": "ASD"}, 
 ]
```

then you could use `json` module

```
import json

print json.dumps(s)
```

Comment: hello I am using Django rest framework , Can I eliminate by changing any settings

Comment: do you have any problem with this in Django rest framework ? then ask new question with **full information**. Always  add **full information**. I don't use Django rest framework but I expect  that rest framework should convert it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You're example is not a valid Python string, but I assume what you have is the "stringified" form of a dictionary:

```
d1 = [{"course_id": u"1", "course_name": u"Angular", "course_img": "sas"},
     {"course_id": u"2", "course_name": u"SMAI", "course_img": "ASD"}]
s = str(D)
print(repr(s))
```

Result:

```
"[{'course_id': u'1', 'course_name': u'Angular', 'course_img': 'sas'}, {'course_id': u'2', 'course_name': u'SMAI', 'course_img': 'ASD'}]"
```

If you want to convert that to a valid json string, you can use `ast.literal_eval` to get the original dictionary back, the serialize it properly with `json.dumps`:

```
import ast
d2 = ast.literal_eval(s)
print(d1 == d2) # Did we get original dictionary?

import json
s2 = json.dumps(d2)
print(repr(s2))
```

Result:

```
True
'[{"course_id": "1", "course_name": "Angular", "course_img": "sas"}, {"course_id": "2", "course_name": "SMAI", "course_img": "ASD"}]'
```